# ICS rendering webview with narrow width

Tags: android, webkit, webview, android-webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

So, I have a simple app that loads an image board in a webview.  Everything looks great on most versions of Android except ICS.  First, the rendered page no longer fills the parent, instead filling about 80% of the viewport.  Second, the images and text from posts on the page are wrapped into narrow columns filling about 45% of the width of the viewport.

I realize it could be an issue with how 4.0+ is reading the elements of this wakaba image board (xhtml), but I've hit a wall looking into that.  Perhaps someone could explain what changed with ICS webviews to help me isolate the problem?  Is this an issue with webkit?

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

src:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  wv = new WebView(this);
  WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
  webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
  webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
  webSettings.setMinimumFontSize(48);
  webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
  webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
  webSettings.setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
  setContentView(R.layout.main );
  getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
      wv.loadUrl("http://example.com");
      wv.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
  wv.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
}
```

Example of html posts that are squished:

```
<span class="filesize">File: <a target="_blank" href="/b-/src/1329696064044.png">1329696064044.png</a> -(<em>1063442 B, 1433x1080</em>)</span> <span class="thumbnailmsg">Thumbnail displayed, click image for full size.</span><br />
<a target="_blank" href="/b-/src/1329696064044.png"> <img src="/b-/thumb/1329696064044s.jpg" width="500" height="376" alt="1063442" class="thumb" /></a>    <a name="2058"></a> 
<label><input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="2058" /> <span class="filetitle"></span>  <span class="postername">Anonymous</span> 02/19 17:01</label> <span class="reflink">
<a href="/b-/res/2058.html#i2058">No.2058</a>  </span>&nbsp; [<a href="/b-/res/2058.html">Reply</a>] <blockquote> <p>I&#39;m not saying he&#39;s real&#44; but he&#39;s real.<br />
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkJZYxWAhUA&amp;feature=related" rel="nofollow">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkJZYxWAhUA&amp;feature=related</a></p>  </blockquote>     <br clear="left" /><hr />
```

A preemptive thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting this as well on ICS Webview, which seems to be very unpredictable.

What seemed to cause my narrow width problem was having both `setUseWideViewPort(true)` and `setUseWideViewPort(true)`. So only have one of those and see if it solves the problem.